# Unable to resolve service while trying to activate Startup

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection, serenity-platform

I'm trying to access IHttpContextAccessor And IUserRetrieve services within my Events.OnSignedIn method in my Configure Services.

The below line of code worked in an older version of .net core however, in .NET CORE 5.0 this no longer works.

Any Suggestions?

```
            o.Events.OnSignedIn = async ctx =>
            {
                var claims = ctx.Principal;

                var user = Dependency.Resolve<IUserRetrieveService>().ByUsername(ctx.Principal.Identity.Name) as UserDefinition;
                var remoteIpAddress = Dependency.Resolve<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
                if (remoteIpAddress.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
                {
                    remoteIpAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(remoteIpAddress).AddressList
                    .First(x => x.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
                }


             
            };
```

[image]

Comment: How would I be able to utilize IHttpContextAccessor in my ConfigureServices?

Comment: If the startup class is where you add the IHttpContextAccessor service to the DI-container, it's impossible for startup to have it as a dependency in its constructor. *It's like you want to drive in a car before it's built.* 

You can however still sort-of access the HttpContext in configure services. But it's more or less a delayed access. Since it doesn't exist until a request comes in. It might work for your use case, and there are a couple of other ways to solve the problem, but it's unclear why you need the HttpContext and what it is you're trying to configure with it?

Comment: I'm trying to get the username/ip within Events.OnSignedIn which is within my Configure Services method. @Dennis1679

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#services-injected-into-startup

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Update the post acordingly as it is difficult to view code in the comments

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks. I have updated the post to give more context.

Comment: Please provide actual code and not images.

Comment: Also note that [CookieSignedInContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookiesignedincontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0) provides access to the HttpContext which can be used to resolve request services as needed.

Comment: @rahulchawla any feedback on the provided answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: [Services injected into Startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0#services-injected-into-startup)

> Only the following services can be injected into the Startup constructor when using the Generic Host (IHostBuilder):
>
> - IWebHostEnvironment
> - IHostEnvironment
> - IConfiguration

Note that [CookieSignedInContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.cookiesignedincontext?view=aspnetcore-5.0) provides access to the current request's `HttpContext` which can be used to resolve request services as needed.

```
o.Events.OnSignedIn = async ctx => {
    var claims = ctx.Principal;
    IServiceProvider services = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices;
    var user = services.GetService<IUserRetrievService>().ByUsername(ctx.Principal.Identity.Name) as UserDefinition;
    var remoteIpAddress = ctx.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access dependencies within a cookie event, you should register an `options.EventsType`. eg;

```cs
services.AddSingleton<MyEvents>();
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
        options.EventsType = typeof(MyEvents);
    });

public class MyEvents : CookieAuthenticationEvents{
    public MyEvents (... dependencies here...){}
    ...
}
```